# Extract maximum number from text string

Tags: r

I am trying to get the maximum value from the column `Number struck` in a data frame. As you can see some of the rows have a range. Thanks in advance.

```
Aircraft    Number struck
B-757-200   2 to 10
B-737-300   1
B-737-300   1
B-727-200   1
UNKNOWN     1
C-550       1
B-727-200   1
CITATION II 1
DA-2000     1
B-737-500   1
B-737-300   2 to 10
UNKNOWN     2 to 10
HAWKER 800  1
MD-80       11 to 100
B-737-400   1
B-737       1
B-767-300   2 to 10
EMB-120     2 to 10
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(Aircraft = c("B-757-200", "B-737-300", "B-737-300", 
"B-727-200", "UNKNOWN", "C-550", "B-727-200", "CITATION II", 
"DA-2000", "B-737-500", "B-737-300", "UNKNOWN", "HAWKER 800", 
"MD-80", "B-737-400", "B-737", "B-767-300", "EMB-120"), Number.struck = c("2 to 10", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2 to 10", "2 to 10", 
"1", "11 to 100", "1", "1", "2 to 10", "2 to 10")), .Names = c("Aircraft", 
"Number.struck"), row.names = c(NA, -18L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Try `sapply(strsplit(df1[,2], '\\D+'), function(x) max(as.numeric(x)))`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work

```
res <- as.numeric(as.character(unlist(strsplit(gsub("[a-zA-Z]","",df$Number.struck),"\\s"))))
max(res,na.rm=T)
```